# connect to mongodb on dokku, remote

Tags: mongodb, docker, dokku

I was trying to follow this information here on how to connect remotely 
https://github.com/dokku/dokku-mongo/issues/72

I am using robomongo to connect and I have entred the SSH info correctly
I have tried to use usernames and password of my VPS also root and admin and my SSH info also info here /var/lib/dokku/services/mongo/mydb

always get auth error

what password and username should I use ?
anu idead ?

note: the ports are exposed ..

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the authentication information for a given dokku service using the following command:

`dokku mongo:info SERVICE_NAME`

Comment: still can't connect. got the string.. (username:pw@ip:port) but doesn't connect

Comment: If you are connecting from an app in Dokku, that app must be linked to the service. If you are connecting remotely, you should expose the service and use your host's IP and the exposed port to connect.